# git resolving previous merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge

Once I've merged my branch with another.
I haven't resolve the conflicts that were made.
I have been merging till recently, till I figured out that lots of "<<<<" were added to my code.
I believe it's related to the unresolved merge conflicts.
I try to solve the conflicts in my last merge with "theirs" strategy. 
Unfortunately, it didn't have any effect on the previous unresolved conflicts.
How do I resolve all the unresolved conflicts with the "theirs strategy"?

Thanks!

Comment: You seemed confused about how Git marks a file after a merge.  The `<<<<` and `====` markers you see is how Git lists both versions of a conflict.

Comment: I want to delete those <<<< and accept all "theirs" changes... My code can't run with those marks.

Comment: Then resolve the conflict by hand.

Comment: I want to resolve the conflicts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try reset the code then merge the code again.

say you are on branchA and want to merge branchB

`git reset --hard branchA`

`git merge -X theirs branchB`

Comment: reset is really a bad idea, it will delete all my followed commits.